# How do I configure "flask" to just run files from the browser?

Tags: python, flask

How to configure "flask" so that you can just create a file with the necessary code in a folder on the server and call it from the browser, like in PHP?

Example: http://example.com/my_flask_file_with_python_code.py

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to run Python code in the client's browser (i.e. client side) ?

Comment: Yes. I have a hosting with 'flask' installed on it, and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create such a folder in which you can simply place the '.py' files and access them from the browser on the computer. Exactly how php files behave.

Comment: So, you mean to say that you want to run python scripts (.py files) when you visit a URL. 

For example, if you have a file named: `foo.py`, then you want to execute this file `foo.py` when you make a request to `http://example.com/foo`.  

If that's the case, then first thing - the file won't be executed on the client's browser. It will be executed on the server. Even PHP works like that. It is executed on the server side, not on the machine of the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain the question first.  OP wants an ability to execute python scripts, when hitting a particular URL - possibly via Flask.

**Two possible ways I can think of**

**Option 1**

1. Use some production grade webserver - like Apache or Nginx, in front of your Flask app.
2. And then, write CGI scripts (in Python) - which will directly run when you hit a particular request. You can possibly follow this tutorial for the same - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

**Option 2**

1. Get the URL from location and based on the name, simply launch scripts and return the response.
2. *Something like*:

   ```
   @app.route('/scripts/<script_name>')
   def run_script():
     proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", script_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
     proc.wait()
     return proc.stdout.read()
   ```
3. P.S. I won't recommend this, but just stating here for sake of completeness.